# Jmeter - How to set Jmeter to pick up specific Java version (windows)

Tags: jmeter

My windows system has two Java versions: 15 & 17

I want to make Jmeter pick up version 15.

I set path as: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin`

And JAVA_HOME as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2`

When I do: `java -version` I have:

[image]

But still seems like Jmeter is picking up Java 17 due to an exception when I run code that contains `JSR223 Assertion`

```
2022-05-12 13:40:51,300 ERROR o.a.j.a.JSR223Assertion: Problem in JSR223 script: JSR223 Assertion
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 61
```

How to 'force' Jmeter to pick up java 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sufficient to set the Java version you want to use to be ahead of other Javas in [PATH environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) and JMeter will pick it up.

```
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin";%PATH%
```

In order to check what Java version JMeter is using you can add a [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) configured like:

[image]

and look for `java.version` property in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

[image]

or just look for `java.version` line in the [JMeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

[image]

Comment: Even if I do that, I still have java.version=17.0.2 as the debug sampler output. Any other suggestions?

Comment: using jmeter version: 5.4.3

Comment: I don't know how you're running JMeter, it might be the case the path to Java executable is hard-coded somewhere in [jmeter.bat](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/bin/jmeter.bat) startup script. If you're getting Java version as 15 in the command line try running JMeter as `java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar` from JMeter's "bin" folder. More information: [Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)

Comment: Launching Jmeter through 'ApacheJMeter.jar' located under /bin folder

Comment: When I run as you mentioned above is fine: it says: 'java.version=15.0.2'

Answer (score 2):

If you want just jMeter to use a specific java without changing environment variables, just create a .bat file and start jMeter after setting the path you want:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%
call jmeter.bat
```

Run the bat and it will open jMeter with the paths set.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  Even on jmeter 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Milk and honey for me here were:

1 set path as: `set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin";%PATH%`

2 lunch Jmeter from cmd as: `java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar`

coz launching from 'ApacheJMeter.jar' probably initiated hardcode java version

the alternative is the creation of .bat launcher as:

a) create startJmeter.bat

b) put inside

```
c: 
cd C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin
java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

In `jmeter.bat` is written that you can create a file called `setenv.bat` and set all your custom variables there. It will be automatically called if you execute `jmeter.bat`

From jmeter.bat

> Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a
> script setenv.bat in JMETER_HOME/bin to keep your customizations
> separate.

Comment: i dont get your point, can you clarify your opinion? thanks

Comment: You don't have to set PATH variables or other variables in your OS. Just create the file an set you variables you need.